# Would it be possible to package in a JVM with games for modern consoles?

Tags: java, libgdx, porting

I really like LibGDX (using Java). It has a great community with a lot of resources and many nice features included. But I would also love to develop games for the Nintendo Switch, PS4 and Xbox One.

I know that those consoles do not natively support Java applications. But with the way those consoles work (usually running somewhat modern operating systems and often just being forks of Linux), would it be possible to package a game with a JVM wrapper to support those platforms individually? The whole point of Java is that the JVM can be adapted to many platforms, so it must be possible with some work, right?

If so, what performance penalties would there be and what would be involved in this endeavor?

Thanks!

Comment: Is Minecraft on PS4? Yes. Question answered.

Comment: You are wrong. Minecraft was not ported over to the PS4 using a JVM. The only edition of Minecraft using Java is the PC version. Microsoft ported the game from scratch to C# (using XNA and probably Monogame now) to the xbox and now on various other platforms.